# How to compare 2 inventory lists using R?

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes. One is a more up to date inventory list (Product, Quantity), and one is an older inventory list.

I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to produce a list of all new product (product that is in the new list but not the old one. This can either be a brand new product, or an addition to the "Quantity" variable with the same Product).

I am also looking for the opposite - essentially trying to produce a list of all "lost" product (product that is completely removed or quantity goes down)

I tried doing some anti joins/inner joins with no luck. Anyone have any suggestions on an efficient way to do this in R?

Datasets:

```
n<-6
new <- data.frame(quantity=1:n, 
              product=rep(LETTERS[1:6], n/6)
)

n<-4
old <- data.frame(quantity=1:n, 
              product=rep(LETTERS[1:4], n/4)
)
```

here, the result would be 5/E and 6/F as new products, and nothing in the lost products

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Maybe a function like [arsenal::comparedf](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arsenal/vignettes/comparedf.html)  can help.

Comment: A starting point might be using `setdiff`. Something like `setdiff(new$product, old$product)` would show you the items that are in the new list, but not in the old list (note the order of the lists in the function is important)

Answer (score 1):

You really want set operations like `setdiff`,  `union`, `intersect`, and `setequal`. As you are looking for "most efficient": You might consider the `data.table` versions: https://rdrr.io/cran/data.table/man/setops.html

A list of all the different products can be gained via `setdiff`:

```
> setdiff(new$product, old$product)
[1] "E" "F"
```

And to look up, which are *new* and which are *lost*, you can use `%in%`:

```
sd <- setdiff(new$product, old$product)
which(sd %in% new$product)
which(sd %in% old$product)
```